# How to create a window with multiple figures (not subplot or hold) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a GUI I am working on. In one of the axes I want to plot multiple figures and be able to click through them one at a time. Each figure has 2 subplots (see image link).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqVXg.png

Is there existing code to plot multiple figures in a single window with next/previous buttons, or a way to do this within an axes or panel in GUIDE? I cannot just create 'x' number of panels and toggle visibility because the number of figures that are being plotted depends on the data size being processed.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't programmatically generate panels.

Comment: Is it possible to create additional panels using a loop and panel within guide? I cannot find an example of adding panels to a GUI within a loop.

Comment: It is, though it would be marginally simpler in a programmatic GUI. That being said, depending on the number of variables that could potentially add a lot of objects into memory, is there a reason you want to do it with panels (or similar) rather than updating the plotted data?

Comment: Originally i had hoped to preload each figure before inspecting them. I think it will be easier to just tie a function to a next button that plots the next figure instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a programmatic approach to explore the answer the explicit question. This function 'loads' a dummy set of data and generates `N` number of panels based on how many variables are loaded. In this case it's the length of the data structure I create. You can navigate between panels using the buttons.

```
function testcode()
% Initialize GUI
h.myfig = figure;

h.loadbutton = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.myfig, ...
    'Style', 'Pushbutton', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.015 0.75 0.3 0.2], ...
    'String', 'Load Data', ...
    'Callback', {@loaddata} ...
    );

h.previousplotbutton = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.myfig, ...
    'Style', 'Pushbutton', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.015 0.35 0.3 0.2], ...
    'String', 'Previous Plot', ...
    'Tag', 'previous', ...
    'Callback', {@switchpanel} ...
    );

h.nextplotbutton = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', h.myfig, ...
    'Style', 'Pushbutton', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.015 0.10 0.3 0.2], ...
    'String', 'Next Plot', ...
    'Tag', 'next', ...
    'Callback', {@switchpanel} ...
    );

h.plotpanel = uipanel( ...
    'Parent', h.myfig, ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.33 0 0.66 1], ...
    'Title', 'Plotting Panel' ...
    );

guidata(h.myfig, h);

function loaddata(hObj, ~)
h = guidata(hObj);

% Make some dummy data
for ii = 1:5
    mydata(ii).x = 1:10;
    mydata(ii).y = rand(10, 1);
end

nvariables = length(mydata);
h.plotsubpanels = genpanels(h.plotpanel, nvariables, mydata);

guidata(hObj, h);

function h = genpanels(parentobj, N, mydata)
% Generate array of panels and axes objects

for ii = 1:N
    h.panel(ii) = uipanel( ...
        'Parent', parentobj, ...
        'BorderWidth', 0, ...
        'BorderType', 'none', ...
        'Title', sprintf('Panel %u', ii), ...
        'TitlePosition', 'centertop', ...
        'Tag', sprintf('%u', ii), ...
        'Visible', 'off' ...
        );
    h.topax(ii) = subplot(2, 1, 1, 'Parent', h.panel(ii));
    h.botax(ii) = subplot(2, 1, 2, 'Parent', h.panel(ii));

    plot(h.topax(ii), mydata(ii).y, mydata(ii).x);
    plot(h.botax(ii), mydata(ii).x, mydata(ii).y);
end

h.panel(1).Visible = 'on';

function switchpanel(hObj, eventdata)
h = guidata(hObj);
temp = {h.plotsubpanels.panel.Visible}; % Pull panel visibility
currentpanel = find(strcmp(temp, 'on'), 1); % Find the active panel
npanels = length(temp); % Find number of panels

switch lower(eventdata.Source.Tag) % Figure out which button was pushed
    case 'next'
        if currentpanel < npanels % Make sure we're not at the end
            h.plotsubpanels.panel(currentpanel).Visible = 'off';
            h.plotsubpanels.panel(currentpanel + 1).Visible = 'on';
        end
    case 'previous'
        if currentpanel > 1 % Make sure we're not at the beginning
            h.plotsubpanels.panel(currentpanel).Visible = 'off';
            h.plotsubpanels.panel(currentpanel - 1).Visible = 'on';
        end
end
guidata(hObj, h);
```

The only significant addition that wouldn't be in your GUIDE gui is the `genpanels` function, but it would be straightforward to add in and call. You just need to make sure you're utilizing a method (such as [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) or [`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html)/[`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html)) to pass the handles around your GUI so you can access the subpanels/axes at a later time. Hopefully this helps.